# Change background to a random colour via a Button

Tags: python, tkinter, button, background-color

as you can read in the title, i'm trying to set the background of a frame to a random colour everytime the button is pressed. I set up a variable which holds the colours. I tested that and it does print everytime a different random colour. But when i assaign it to the Button, nothing changes..

```
import random
from tkinter import *


def overlord():

counter = 0

main_frame = Tk()

main_frame.title("I'm bored pls Help")
main_frame.attributes("-fullscreen", True)
# main_frame.config(background="black")

counter_l = Label(text=counter)

random_colour_b = Button(main_frame, bg="black", fg="gold", text="Click Me!", font="Arial 20",
                         command=lambda: random_colour_b)
exit_b = Button(text="Kill Me!", bg="black", fg="red", font="Arial 20", command=main_frame.destroy)

counter_l.pack()

random_colour_b.pack()
exit_b.pack()

main_frame.mainloop()
```

Thats my function for the Frame. I can't seem to find an answer which tells me how to change the frame background with the Button. Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not competent in Tkinter, but there is a solution (even if terms is wrong):

`command` parameter accepts a function that performs an action on your frame. You used it  in incorrect way

```
from random import choice
from tkinter import *


def overlord():
    counter = 0

    main_frame = Tk()

    main_frame.title("I'm bored pls Help")
    main_frame.attributes("-fullscreen", True)

    counter_l = Label(text=counter)

    random_colour_b = Button(
        main_frame, bg="black", fg="gold", text="Click Me!", font="Arial 20",
        command=lambda: main_frame.config(background=choice(["black", "white"]))
    )
    exit_b = Button(text="Kill Me!", bg="black", fg="red", font="Arial 20", command=main_frame.destroy)

    counter_l.pack()

    random_colour_b.pack()
    exit_b.pack()

    main_frame.mainloop()
    
    
overlord()
```